IT Professional interested in research
I have Bachelors of Engineering degree in Electronics & Communication from India. After that I have 5 year 9 months of experience from India and 2 year 2 month experience in Germany. I am interested in going in IT research or pursuing PhD from Germany or Online. But, I don't have masters degree neither I have time to pursue master's agree. Can somebody guide me to how to proceed and is there any possible way to proceed in research?

Does this answer your question? How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in Country X?
